What is an absolutely irreducible smooth curve and how to determine if a curve is as such over a finite field F_q?
I'm new to this cite but I will try my best to convey my question in the best way possible.
I was learning about Hasse-Weil Bound from Terence Tao's website and I had many questions from the beginning. In the first paragraph of the website it uses a term called "absolutely irreducible smooth projective curve" I know what a projective curve means, but I don't know what does "absolutely irreducible" mean and have questions about "smooth curve" (This might be 2 seperate questions to be answered).
I searched on Wikipedia and on this website, but wasn't fulfilled. I want to understand which curves defined over $F_q$ are absolutely irreducible and smooth, where $F_q$ is a finite field with $q=p^n$. According to the answer on mathcurve.com the projective algebraic curve $F(X,Y,Z)$ is smooth if the system of equations to $F(X,Y,Z)=0, \frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(X,Y,Z)=0, \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(X,Y,Z)=0, \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}(X,Y,Z)=0$ has the unique solution $(0,0,0)$ which is not defined on the projective plane. As we're working on $F_q$ which has characteristic $p$ a prime, does the system of equations $=0$ actually mean $0 (mod p)$? I have tried this for a projective elliptic curve of the form $zy^2=x^3+az^2x+bz^3$ setting $F(x,y,z)=x^3+az^2x+bz^3-zy^2$ solved the predescribed system of equations, and found out that the elliptic curve was smooth if $27b^2+4a^3\neq0(mod p)$ (Please correct me if I'm wrong) This is what I understand from smoothness and hopefully it's correct. Is there any possible way to categorize which projective curves of some degree aren't smooth, for example for elliptic curves it was easy.
On the other part of my question of "absolutely irreducible" on wikipedia it tells that a curve is absolutely irreducible if it's irreducible on its algebraically closed field extension. If the field was Q, Z or R the field extension of it would simply be C, and it would mean being irreducible on C. But we're working on $F_q$ and I don't even know how is the algebraically closed extension of a finite field is, and even if I do know, how could I ever know if the curve is irreducible on that field?
In this video of Aleph$0$, it says the number of solutions to an elliptic curve on $F_q$ $=q+1-E$ where E is an integer as such
$2\sqrt{q} \geq E \geq 0$. This confirms the Hasse Weil bound on Terence Tao's website cause it's the case where the genus $g=1$. If that can be said, I believe every elliptic curve is "absolutely irreducible" on $F_q$. (Please correct me, if wrong)

absolutely irreducible & smooth means that the curve is smooth over every finite extension of $F_q$, i.e. that your system of equations has the only solution $(0.0.0)$ not just in $F_q$ but also in every finite extension $F_{q^k}$ of $F_q$
